# Integration by parts (multiple variables)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integration-by-parts

Is there anyone who can help me explaining the following integration by parts problem?

$$\iint \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \frac{\partial g^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^2}\right)h(t,x) dt dx$$

where $f$, $g$ and $h$ are all functions in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times\mathbb{R}$ where $h$ is smooth with compact support in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times\mathbb{R}$.

I found the following expression but I am completely overburdened with these multiple variables...

$$\iint \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right) dt dx$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you precise the variables for each functions? Is it only $(t,x)$ or is there some function composition?

Comment: no composition, just $(t,x)$ in every case